# Batch Renaming of Shapefiles using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.4

I have 100 shapefiles that share the same initial 44 characters. I would like to remove those initial identical 44 characters. The unique portion of the shapefile is the line number, i.e. Line_1006_1007. I want to rename the shapefile with the line numbers. Additionally, I want to remove the .kml before the .shp in the name. Here are three examples of the shapefile name below.

"Lines_P_10345_-_600_Mile_Project_Collection_Line_1006_1007.kml.shp"

"Lines_P_10345_-_600_Mile_Project_Collection_Line_921_920_906.kml.shp"

"Lines_P_10345_-_600_Mile_Project_Collection_Line_3130.kml.shp"

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 with all of the extensions available.

Comment: You can use Python for this, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-files-in-python

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use    `Rename_management (in_data, out_data, {data_type})` (in arcpy)
This would be an easy script to write and I think the best way to do this. In Python you can use the `strip()` function.

So you'd write a loop using something like `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` and within that loop you can use something like `out_data = in_data.strip("annoying44charstring...")` on each "item" within your loop.

The python method provided by @BERA would work well as long as you don't have other files that might be affected though if they had the same 44 character string that might be OK to rename those too (depends on what you want it to do).

Answer (score 2):

As BERA already mentioned, you should ideally use Python for this. Look at the link provided above and start from there.

To start with, I'd recommend the **following workflow**:

1. Set the workspace to the folder containing the shapefiles you want to process
2. List all your shapefiles in the workspace
3. Iterate through the listed shapefiles and:

   - Read out their file names (cut the path, i.e. using the `os.path.split()` function, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507298/splitting-path-strings-into-drive-path-and-file-name-parts) for more details)
   - cut the left 44 characters and the right 8 characters (including the    points) from the file name (using something like `newfileName =    filename[44:-8]` which returns a string from position 45 (0 being the    first position) excluding the last 8; see [this link](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) for more    details)
   - copy the feature class (i.e. using `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeautreClass_conversion()` being iterated using the `newfileName` (together with the desired output path) as the outputfile
4. Optionally delete all the original shapefiles in the list

Answer (score 0):

If you have R, you could copy and paste this code into R. It should do exactly what you want.

```
###Set your working directory to wherever you are keeping your files####
setwd("C:/Users/Ash/Desktop/YourFolderWithYourStuff")

temp = list.files(pattern="*.kml.shp")
####This will delete all the text up to and including the word 'Line_'####
for(x in 1:length(temp)) {
variablea = gsub(".*Line_","",temp[x])
    file.rename(temp[x],variablea)
}
####This will replace .kml.shp with .shp#####
myvar=list.files(pattern="*.kml.shp")

for(x in 1:length(myvar)) {
evennewerfilename = gsub(".kml.shp",".shp",myvar[x])
    file.rename(myvar[x],evennewerfilename)
}
```

This code will only rename the `.shp` files. To rename your `.prj`, and`.dbf` files, you will need to run lines 1-9 again, but change the pattern from `*.kml.shp` to the respective file extension you want to change.

Comment: I've tested my code with your file names. It works.

Comment: It will loop through all hundred files in about five seconds.

Comment: You can download R here: https://cloud.r-project.org/

Once you download it, all you need to do it open it, copy the code I wrote, change the working directory to where your files are stored, and paste it into the console.

Comment: No, this code will only rename the actual `.shp` file, the `.dbf` and such will retain the old name, rendering the dataset broken/unusable!

Comment: Oh, good point @til_b! If Ash has even a little coding experience they can modify the code to rename the .dbf, .prj etc. as well. The only part of the code that would require changing is the pattern in line 4. They wouldn't need to use the second half of the code (lines 10-16) for anything other than the actual .shp file.

Comment: @til_b, I edited the question to include your suggestions. If you downvoted the answer for that reason I would appreciate you removing your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Don't feel comfortable with the programming, her's an old DOS trick.

open cmd prompt, cd to the folder where your hundred shapefiles are.

dir *.shp /b >files.txt

now you have a listing of all your shapefiles. Open this txt file in excel. Note the file names are in A, so right click on A, select insert, and type in 'rename" drag this to the end of your records.

Now copy the B column to C. Now in the C do a find replace on 'Lines_P_10345_-_600_Mile_Project_Collection_' with ''(nothing) it should remove the extra leading part of the file name you don't want. Now do another find/replace with the '.KML' to remove it.  Lastly on the B and C columns do one last find/replace 'shp' to '*'

Now save it. quit excel. I did this with some of my file as an example, when you open the text file you should see something like this:

rename  MCParcels.* oldMCParcel.*
rename  mercerCo.*  oldmercerCo.*
with your file names.

Now the fun part rename file.txt to files.bat, use the cmd prompt to do this so you don't get files.txt.bat, you want files.bat.

Now in the CMD prompt just type files.bat and hit enter, it will rename them and all the associated files. You can also just double click on the file.bat and it will run.

This trick takes a few minutes to setup but I've renamed 1500 jpgs in a few seconds.